# How to decide your first self-project for Data Science/Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, project-planning

Suppose a complete beginner(in the field of data analysis/data science), which is my case indeed, decided to make a project for his/her resume.

These are the following skills he have learnt:

1. Python(pandas, NumPy, seaborn/matplotlib)- 2 years of experience(intermediate level)

2)SQL- 1 month experience have knowledge of basic querying

3. PowerBI/Tableau- beginner level familiarity

Now, he wanna learn by practicing thus creating an end-to-end project on data analysis which contains Problem statement, Research question, hypothesis and EDA verifying or disproving his hypothesis.

But as beginner it's very tough task. May you please guide me how do I make my first project including these parameters.(Additionally, the work experience is 0 )

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the resume, I can see you must be okay for doing some EDA tasks.
You've learnt Pandas, so you can work with data frames and datasets.

Now it's time to challenge yourself!

For your fist project, look at this dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ravindrasinghrana/job-description-dataset/data

Try to get any insight from it.

Put columns data on the plot/chart and try to get relation/correlation between columns.

Do some Statistics, get the max. min, std, ... of the numerical columns and try to explain it. (Do some storytelling with that data)

Does it make sense to convert any categorical data/column to numerical data or vice versa?

Extract the Jobs and countries with highest/lowest Salary and put it on the plot/chart. Is there any relation between Salary and the location of that Job?

Could you see why some jobs are more demanding and some are rare for hiring based on any other info in the dataset? Maybe there is no logical answer to this, but try to find it!

Is there any relation between the Experience and Salary?

Try to plot the most frequent Job Titles as a World Cloud?

Group skills based on each Job Title and get the 5 top skills needed for each Job Categories

Which Countries are hiring for "Software Engineer" jobs, the most?

Find any relation between Work type and the latitude and longitude. for example.

**I would say the demand for Tech/IT/Engineering jobs in rural locations are rare, and most kinds of tech jobs are in Capital/Big cities. Can you confirm or disapprove this hypothesis base on this dataset?**

Create as many plots as you can and try to describe them, find any relation between the data.

Find the Anomaly/outliers/corrupt data if there is any and report them.

See there are lots of things you can do with any data.

At the end, try to make a text repot of anything you find with this EDA and analysis. **This is the most important part.**

Go ahead and I wish you luck.

Comment: Didn't expected someone to give me a EDA project topic . Thank you so much.. Will definitely do this :)

Comment: @SwayamJha you're welcome. I appreciate if you could mark the answer as an accepted one.